# Extract query string variable from Links

Tags: r

```
http://example.com/?example_id=123&second_id=25
```

I need to get those two id `example_id` and `second_id`.Is there any package or inbuilt function available for it?

Comment: You should use a real URL parser vs the hack answer. You're working with an entity with a defined structure and multiple R libraries to handle them properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `stringr::str_extract_all` for this:

```
stringr::str_extract_all("http://example.com/?example_id=123&second_id=25", pattern = "\\d+")
```

Comment: What if the variable contains character?

Comment: Then it obviously won't work anymore ;-) Feel free to adjust that regex as you need it. I only answered according to your question (what function...) and your example.